# Check if Stripe customer exists

Tags: laravel

I would like to check if a customer already exists so that I can update his details or if he does not exist create it by starting a new subscription.

I created this, but I believe there is something wrong.

```
if(Auth::user()->subscribed('default')) {
                
                $stripe->customers->update(Auth::user()->stripe_id, array([
                    'email' => Auth::user()->email,
                    'name' => 'Example Example',
                    'phone' => '322234455556',
                    'address' => [
                        'city' => 'Alcatraz',
                        'line1' => 'Via Dalle Palle',
                        'postal_code' => '96011',
                        'state' => 'Italia'
                    ]
                ]));
                
            } else {
            
                $stripe->customers->create([
                    'description' => 'Example Example',
                    'email' => Auth::user()->email,
                    'name' => 'Example Example',
                    'phone' => '322234455556',
                    'address' => [
                        'city' => 'Alcatraz',
                        'line1' => 'Via Dalle Palle',
                        'postal_code' => '96011',
                        'state' => 'Italia'
                    ]
                ]);
            }
```

---

I think there is a mistake, because when I go to create a new subscription with a newly registered user, therefore not present on Stripe as a customer, it does nothing but create me two entries as in the image below.

[image]

Comment: `->update(Auth::user()->stripe_id, array([])` I don't use spark So I'm assuming the first parameter is correct, but you have a double array `array([])` you should either use `array(...)` or `[...]`

Comment: I corrected, but unfortunately it creates duplicates as in the example I put in the first post.

Comment: Perhaps because `Auth::user()->subscribed('default')` returns `false`.  But I believe, I don't have enough information to help more than that

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
$stripeCustomer = Auth::user()->createOrGetStripeCustomer([
                    'description' => 'Example Example',
                    'email' => Auth::user()->email,
                    'name' => 'Example Example',
                    'phone' => '322234455556',
                    'address' => [
                        'city' => 'Alcatraz',
                        'line1' => 'Via Dalle Palle',
                        'postal_code' => '96011',
                        'state' => 'Italia'
                    ]
                ]);
```